# displaying data from more than one table in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am using a web form asp.net application in which I have to present a SAP Crystal Report. Application is about a CAR SERVICE Center. I am using VS 2013 and SQL Server 2012.

In my SQL Server I have tables as follows

```
INVOICE
------------------------------------------------------
Invid           Serv_Req_Id         Total     Final     Advance
------------------------------------------------------
INV16060006 SRQ16060008   2300.00   2185.00   1500.00
------------------------------------------------------


Services
------------------------------------------------------
JObId       Serv_Req_Id           serviceid     qty   unitprice
--------------------------------------------------------
JOB16060008 SRQ16060008   SRV16050002   1     300.00
JOB16060009 SRQ16060008   SRV16050005   1     2000.00
```

Which means for an Invoice there are multiple services a person can do.

The invoice should be displayed in CR as below:

```
------------------- --------------------------------------
Invoice details xxx xxx xxx xxx 
                xxxx   xxxx 
------------------- ------------------
services

xxxx   xxxxx xxxxx   xxxxx<br/>
xxxx   xxxxx xxxxx   xxxxx<br/>
xxxx   xxxxx xxxxx   xxxxx<br/>
xxxx   xxxxx xxxxx   xxxxx<br/>

total :xxxx 
discount:xxxx 
advance:  xxxx 
grand total: xxxx 

------------------------ ----------------------
```

In database, I tried to create stored procedure but failed. How can I achieve this?

The solution can be by getting these data in some form from database or displaying these in CR.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Take Data from Database in Two Different Table.
2. Add Sub Report in Crystal Report and link with Main Report. Or You can use Single report with two table.

Answer (score 0):

Link both tables on a common field then

Create a group with invoice and place all the invoice details in group header

Place service data in details

Final calculation in group footer